# How can i delete inside of object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How do set array x to empty ?

```
var testObj = {
    x : ['1', '2'],
    y : ['1' , '3']
}
```

To Replace

```
var testObj = {
    x : [],
    y : ['1' , '3']
}
```

Comment: `testObj.x = [];`

Answer (score 1):

Do that :

```
testObj.x = []
```

Hope it helped

Comment: its not worked man

Comment: Can you give us your code ? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reassign the variable, you can also

```js
testObj.x.length = 0;
```